# Why dont i have to free memory from the heap when reallocating?

Tags: c, realloc

So i have this code:

```
/* Dynamic Array Reader */

/* Parameters:
 * n: Number of values to be read
 * 
 * Returns: pointer to the dynamically allocated array
 */
int *dyn_reader(unsigned int n) {
    int* array = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    if (!array)
        return NULL;
    else {
        unsigned int num_read = 0;
        printf("Enter %u integers so they can be put into this array\n", n);
        while (num_read < n) {
            num_read += scanf("%d", array + num_read);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

/* Add to array */

/* Parameters:
 * arr: Existing array of integers
 * num: number of integers in the array before the call
 * newval: new value to be added
 * 
 * Returns: pointer to the allocated array
 */
int *add_to_array(int *arr, unsigned int num, int newval) {
    int* newarray = realloc(arr, (num+1) * sizeof (int)); //allocate one more space
    if (newarray == NULL) //Return original array if failed to allocate
        return arr;

    //free(arr); //free old array -- this throws an error when i try and free up the old array
    newarray[num] = newval;
    return newarray;
}

int main()
{
    /* testing exercise. Feel free to modify */
    int *array = dyn_reader(5);

    array = add_to_array(array, 5, 10);
    array = add_to_array(array, 6, 100);
    array = add_to_array(array, 6, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the main function calls dyn_reader which allocates enough memory to allow there to be n elements in the array. It reads in integers from the user and returns the array.

Then the main function calls add_to_array which realocates enough memory to add one addition element in the array. If it cant, it returns the original array. If the memory reallocation works, i add newval to the end of the array. In this case, i am using a new pointer to store where the newly reallocated array. How come when i try to free the old array (free(arr);), i get an error. Doesn't that pointer still point to memory on the heap and shouldnt i free it?

Comment: Realloc if it moved the memory to be able to extend it deallocate old allocation on success.

Comment: `realloc` will allocate the new amount of memory, and if that is successful, will copy the original memory block across and then free the original block and finally return a pointer to the new memory block. If not successful it returns NULL but the original memory is left intact.

Comment: And realloc can give you the same pointer as return if he managed to just extend your allocation without moving to different address so by free(arr) you would actually free your new reallocated memory.

Comment: Calling free on a pointer to memory, that's since been realloc'd is undefined behaviour, as the pointer may be pointing at garbage.

Comment: Because `realloc` frees it and you're not allowed to free it twice.

Comment: Not relevant to the question but silently failing, as `add_to_array` does, is really bad design. The fact that an allocation fails at some point in time does not mean that a similar or even larger future allocation will also fail. So you could find that `a=add_to_array(a, n, x)` silently fails and subsequently `a=add_to_array(a,n+1,y)` succeeds, at which point `a[n]` is surprisingly uninitialized, probably leading to Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if the realloc moved to a new area of memory, then it does the "free()" for you (so make sure you don't have any other pointers pointing into that array ! ).  The C standard says (at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html ) :

```
The realloc() function shall deallocate the old object pointed to by ptr
```

The linux man page (at https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) makes it more explicit :

```
 If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.
```

Comment: Conceptually, a successful `realloc` **always** frees the old memory and returns new memory with the same contents up to the minimum of the old and new sizes. If the new memory happens to have the same address, that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

If reallocation was successful,  `realloc()` has handled freeing memory related to the earlier pointer.  Note that the *pointer* may not have even changed.

Another problem with `add_to_array()` is that the calling function lacks any indication of success/failure.